# Return 'null' even though value is there

Tags: flutter, dart

So I tried to add the result from this to the object list of data[i].score:

```
List relatif = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  relatif[i] = separasiNis[i] / (separasiNis[i] + separasiPis[i]);
  data[i].score = relatif[i];
}
```

But, when I tried to display it, it said 'null'. I've tried to print the `data[i].score` and there are some value inside it. Here's a snippet how I tried to display it into app.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: data.length,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            data[i].score.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ], 
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

How I defined `data[i].score`:

```
class Database {
  double id, score;

  Database({this.id, this.score});
}

var data = [
    Database(
      id: 1,
    ),
    Database(
      id: 2,
    ),
    Database(
      id: 3,
    ),
    Database(
      id: 4,
    )
  ];
```

Comment: What are the values inside data[i].score?

Comment: Post the code where you defined your `data list` @momo

Comment: Post the complete code with variable initializations

Comment: To @T.TSage  I added it.

Comment: If you are not initialising score it won't have any value to display. @momo

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan the result from the 'relatif' operation

Comment: @momo can you please add the values for separasiNis